# Is it ok to run with unknown video device?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I'm new to Linux and just starting to learn. From what I've read and experimented with there's no more support for older ATI Mobility cards. I resolved a few boot issues with my first install of Ubuntu 12.10 (now on clean install #3) and my system seems to function okay with video unknown. Picture quality is good and no issues with video playback. It functions for my purposes.

Should I leave it as is... or will this cause problems I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Nope!  If it works, it works.

The only thing you might want to consider is that your card may be able to perform better with a specific driver.  With that card, I think the consensus view is to use the radeon driver.  You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

It's probably already installed; Ubuntu does most of the work for you in this respect.  You can run that for a little peace of mind though!

Comment: ATI mobility radeon x300 Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: While your card may generally perform better with proprietary drivers, you should always rely on the free software drivers that come with your system. Those are more stable, better integrated, and require less, if any maintenance work on your site. If your card performs satisfactory, don't start to fiddle around with drivers. If it doesn't you might want to try. And as gh403 so beautifully wrote: If it works, it works.

Comment: @Paul The only thing I meant was if it was using the generic VGA driver.  Which I don't think it is, or the system wouldn't be playing any video :)

Comment: I'm getting better with the terminal and uninstalling/fixing things but I think I'll let it ride for now. It works :)

Comment: That's the spirit! :)  I think you should have the radeon driver without having to do anything else anyway.  Like I said, Ubuntu pretty much just works.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't see that to be a major cause of panic though. My computer (Aspire 1 notebook), after install ubuntu 12.10, says my graphics card is unknown but functions okay. Not come across any bad effects though.

I don't know if there's any technical disadvantages to it showing as "unknown". Its cool, no worries.

:)

Comment: If you're getting Video output, it works as it should. There is no problem beyond aesthetics.